# Find Column Index by referencing Column Name?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

How to get `ColumnIndex` of a `Column` by `ColumnName` from a `DataGridView`?

Here's the pseudo-code:

```
ColumnIndex = ColumnName("SampleName");
```

Comment: Your pseudo-code doesn't reflect your explanations, please edit your post so it gets clearer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest way to do that:

```
myData.Columns.IndexOf(/*DataGridViewColumn*/)
myData.Columns[/*ColumnName*/].Index
```

Or:

```
private void dataGridView_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    int ColumnIndex= dataGridView.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex;       
}
```

Comment: This seems to answer the pseudo-code part, but I didn't understand OP's explanations that way. To me he wants to get the index when he knows the column name.

Comment: he wants to know the **column Index = column Name**  that's why i answered like this @Rafalon sir

Comment: Is it just me or are your answer and your comment inconsistent? OP wants to get the index, and you are getting the name, is there something I'm missing? (I would just have written `int columnIndex = e.ColumnIndex;`) Anyway, your solution only works if the user clicks on a cell, and this isn't mentioned anywhere in the question

Answer (score 6):

You can use `IndexOf`. Like this:

```
var dataGridViewColumn = dataGridView1.Columns[ColumnName];
if (dataGridViewColumn != null)
{
    int index = dataGridView1.Columns.IndexOf(dataGridViewColumn);
}
```

Or use `Index` and  [*Null-conditional*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-conditional-operators) operator(`?.`) like this:

```
var index = dataGridView1.Columns[ColumnName]?.Index;
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the index of a column

```
myDGV.Columns.IndexOf(myDGV.Columns["SampleColumn"];
```

or more simply like you said

```
myDGV.Columns["SampleColumn"].Index;
```